# Possibility of a function which is not a polynomial, but its laplacian (dimension >=2) is a polynomial

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, finite-element-method

I was going through some literature regarding virtual element function spaces.

I was wondering if it is possible for a function $v_h$ to exist such that $v_h \notin P_k$ but $\Delta v_h \in P_{k-2}$ for dimensions greater than or equal to $2$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $v$ is a polynomial, add  a harmonic function that is not a polynomial.  E.g. in dimension $2$, the real part of a non-polynomial entire function of $z = x+iy$ will do.